# How to create a JSON string in c#/NETMF?

Tags: c#, json, string, visual-studio-2010, .net-micro-framework

At present, I am using a string value `MyFinalJSON` to create a string.

the like of `MyFinalJSON += "\"Name\":\"" + myNameString +"\"";`

This seems a very long winded/error prone way of writing in JSON format.

Is there a better/more appropriate way of creating JSON strings? Especially when the JSON string can get very long.

**EDIT**
 Oh sorry I forgot to mention I'm using the NetMF framework, and so there isn't a namespace for `system.web...`, amongst many others

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Best practise would be to use an existing JSON library for .NET

Comment: make an object and then serialize it

Comment: +1, you've shown your existing code and an effort to improve it. As stated in my answer, though, if you google your own title you'll find many answers already.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, these would be great for .NET - but I forgot to mention that i'm using NETMF and so it's slightly more difficult.

Comment: how about [json.netmf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Json.NetMF) ?

Comment: @YuliamChandra, thank you for your suggestion, but I am unable to use it in this case (I'm programming a FEZ Panda, and so Nuget Package manager is not available).

Comment: download and extract [here](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Json.NetMF/1.3.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [json.netmf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Json.NetMF) or download and extract the file from [here](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Json.NetMF/1.3.0)

Github: https://github.com/mweimer/Json.NetMF

From the documentation, here is the usage.

```
string json = JsonSerializer.SerializeObject(o, DateTimeFormat.Default);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right to ask this as it is indeed the longest way of achieving this (although you could've probably google'd it and found your solution within minutes).

Nevertheless, it's called serialisation:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

var myNameString = "DeeMac";
var myObject = { Name: myNameString };
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myObject);
```

NOTE: There are a few different serialization libraries.

Comment: @DeeMac - Thank you for your suggestion, but I can't use System.Web.Script.Serialization as it is not available on the NETMF framework :(

Comment: @jbutler483 - you've edited since the original question I believe. I'm afraid I don't have the experience with NETMF that would allow me to adapt the answer. I think Yuliam Chandra's comment looks like it could be the help you need. Pretty similar in syntax to what you seen above: https://github.com/mweimer/Json.NetMF

Answer (score -3):

try using JavascriptSerializer or NewtonSoft library ...
for JavascriptSerializerClass DeeMac's answer looks fine :)

For the sample for NewtonSoft library According to documentation on [this](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingJSON.htm) link:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);

JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.Converters.Add(new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\json.txt"))
using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, product);
    // {"ExpiryDate":new Date(1230375600000),"Price":0}
}
```